# "Reading-enhanced slide show" - a correct English phrase?

Tags: phrase-request

Would this wording make sense? I am re-editing a slide show putting more time between the text portions, so that they can be read wholly without pausing.

> Would it be correct to call it a **"reading-enhanced slide show"**?

Or else how could it be appropriately named?

Comment: I would just use "a time-adjusted slide show" with a description why you did this.

Answer (score 1):

"Reading-enhanced" would not be correct here. That would be confusing to people. I don't think there's a simple term for what you want to say. You could say "reader-friendly," but that also suggests things like larger font size and greater contrast between font and background.

Comment: Thanks. Thought the term would be problematic. "More reader-convenient", how about that?

Comment: That sounds awkward to me. I think you can say, "more convenient for readers," but "reader-friendly" would be better than "reader-convenient."